# Split large log file based on date criteria, while logging facility is running

Tags: files, logs, dovecot, large-files

the log file is `/var/log/dovecot.info`, >4GB, with date format:

`2019-07-01 01:07:40`

My objective is:

- have the `/var/log/dovecot.info` which starts with `2019-01-01 00:00:00` and contains up to now log entries
- have the `/var/log/dovecot.info.old` which contains log entries before `2019-01-01 00:00:00` (cca 67% of them)
- operation performed without shutting the dovecot daemon if possible

I've tried with `grep` and `tail` with offset, no luck. I also do not know if this can be done without shutting down the `dovecot` safely.

Comment: I suppose it largely hinges on whether dovecot has that file "open" all the time or not. Does syslog write to the file? (hinted at by the possible syslog severity level of `.info` in the filename)

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you could show even just one line of sample data that indicated the timestamp format (in case it's different from 2019-01-01 00:00:00); if it's the same as in the question, it might be worth stating that.

Comment: @JeffSchaller regarding syslog or not, I'll try to find that out. Yes, that's the format: `2019-07-18 09:58:12 `

Comment: @JeffSchaller I can conclude that syslog is used and not Dovecot process. https://wiki2.dovecot.org/Logging

Answer (score 0):

here is partial answer. as per [Dovecot Wiki](https://wiki2.dovecot.org/Logging)
below code creates separate entry weekly.

Save the below scriptlet as `/etc/logrotate.d/dovecot`:

```
/var/log/dovecot*.log {
  weekly
  rotate 4
  missingok
  notifempty
  compress
  delaycompress
  sharedscripts
  postrotate
    doveadm log reopen
  endscript
}
```

would you still want to parse your log file? in that case please post snippet I will be able to help parse then.

Comment: Thanks. But that's logrotate configuration, I'm not looking for that, I want to shrink current file and to keep the rest in separate file(s)

Comment: can you post 3 lines from your log ?

Comment: are you willing to accept a solution where you can cut this big file in smaller chunks and still keeping this big file? as per date. i.e. every file will have logs from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59